# Adding swipe gestures to Smooth Div Scroll

Tags: jquery, swipe, smooth-scrolling, hammer.js

I am trying to add swipe gestures to Smooth Div Scroll plugin by Thomas Kahn, since the plugin is not working on iPads and other smart devices.

Az first i was using hammer.js to add the functionality. This is the code i used on the container div that holds the images:

```
 $("#makeMeScrollable").hammer({
        prevent_default: false,

    })
    .bind("hold tap doubletap transformstart transform transformend dragstart drag dragend release swipe", function(ev) {

    });
```

But unfortunately, the swipe worked once out of 10 times, and there is no way to stop in the middle, it would just slide to one end or the other.

I am interested if anyone has managed to add swipe functionality to Smooth Div Scroll, or if anyone has some other script to recommend for adding mobile gestures, that is maybe better than Hammer.js.

Here is the link to the website, it is still work in progress: http://www.madebym.net/test/index.html

p.s. right now i am using touchSwipe.js, but it seems worse than hammer.js...it doesn't do anything

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the latest update. Smooth Div Scroll 1.3 has support for touch! The documentation on smoothdivscroll.com has not been updated yet but you'll find all the information you need on GitHub: https://github.com/tkahn/Smooth-Div-Scroll